# How to add a newline to a Highchart tooltip?

Tags: highcharts, visualization

```
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
        pointFormat: '{point.x:%b %e %H:%M}: {point.y:.3f}'
    },
```

How to add a new line between %e and %H?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [tooltip formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#tooltip.formatter) then you can customise content.

Answer (score 8):

set property **useHTML** to **true** and you'll be able to use `<br/>` for making a new line

```
tooltip: {
        useHTML: true,
        headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
        pointFormat: '{point.x:%b %e <br/> %H:%M}: {point.y:.3f}'
    },
```